# Unable to collect *.bak files as a single object

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am new to PowerShell.
I wanted to write a simple program to list all *.bak files which I can then either sort by date or size as shown below.

```
$Drives = Get-WMIObject -class win32_logicaldisk -filter "DriveType = 3" ;
foreach ($d in $Drives){
    If (($d.deviceId -ne "C:") -and ($d.VolumeName -ne "PAGEFILE")) {
        $backups += Get-ChildItem -Path $d.deviceID -Recurse -filter *.bak
  }
```

This generally works fine except when say for example D: drive has only one *.bak file.
In that case I get an error.

```
Method invocation failed because [System.IO.FileInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At F:\work\PowerShell\DiskSpace\generate-disk-report-v2.ps1:39 char:13
+     $backups += <<<<  Get-ChildItem -Path $d.deviceID -Recurse -filter *.bak
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

If I add an additional junk.bak to that drive, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that the variable needs to be initialized as an array and `Get-ChildItem` needs to be returned as an array even, or especially, if it's only returning one file.

In your case:

```
$backups = @() - (Before calling Get-ChildItem)
```

and

```
$backups = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $d.deviceID -Recurse -filter *.bak) - (Cast as an array)
```